# Change the secret a Kubernetes deployment expects

Tags: kubernetes

I've been having a recurring problem with a deployment for a particular pod, `fooserviced`, recently. I usually get a `CreateContainerConfigError` when I update the pod, and the detail given is `Error: secrets "fooserviced-envars" not found`. I'm not sure when I named the file this poorly but so far the only solution I've found is to re-add the environment variables file using

```
kubectl create secret generic fooserviced-envars --from-env-file ./fooserviced-envvars.txt
```

So now, when I do `kubectl get secrets` I see both `fooserviced-envars` and `fooserviced-envvars`. I'd like to change the deployment to use `fooserviced-envvars`; how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that secret is on the same namespace. otherwise you cannot use it
2. If you want to change deployment, change your kubernetes deployment yaml file . e.g.

```
env:
   - name: POSTGRES_DB_URL
     valueFrom: 
        secretKeyRef:
          key: postgres_db_url
          name: fooserviced-envars

then kubectl apply your_deployment_file
```

Comment: Yeah, had one line that referenced `fooserviced-envars` and that did it. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the deployment via `kubectl edit deployment deploymentname` which will open an editor and you can change the secret there live.

Another way to do this would be to run `kubectl get deployment deploymentname -o yaml > deployment.yaml`  which will give you the yaml file and you can edit it in your editor and `kubectl apply` the modified yaml.

Comment: This doesn't address my specific issue but it is a good and valid solution, nonetheless. Thank you